# Dejar un número fijo en un Text Field

Tags: flutter

tengo un TextFormField y me gustaría saber si se puede dejar fijo el número 3 al inicio y que no pueda borrarse para que el usuario siga digitando los demás números, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí es posible, primero podrías definir tu `TextEditingController` con el valor inicial que podría ser `3`.

```dart
final controller = TextEditingController(text: '3');
```

Luego le asignas al `TextField` así:

```dart
              TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    inputFormatters: [MyCustomInputFormatter()],
                  )
```

En `inputFormatters` he creado uno personalizado que se llama `MyCustomInputFormatter` y este sería su implementación:

```dart
class MyCustomInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    const firstNumber = '3';
    if (newValue.text.startsWith(firstNumber)) {
      return newValue;
    }
    return newValue.copyWith(
      text: '$firstNumber${newValue.text}',
      selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: newValue.text.length + 1),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva.